# Merge dask dataframes in python failing on dtype, How to change?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have 2 dask dataframes. 
1. df = 100 mill rows
2. q2d = 500000 rows

Both have a common column called uuid, i am trying to merge both the dataframes in dask.

Its fairly simple task -

```
    case = dd.merge(q2d, df, left_on='UUID',right_on='uuid', how='left')
```

Want to add a few columns from df to q2d, by this process and add more cols to the 500K records in the process.
But this fails by error :

```
   ValueError: Mismatched dtypes found in `pd.read_csv`/`pd.read_table`.
   | Column | Found   | Expected |
   +--------+---------+----------+
   | 641860 | float64 | int64    |
   +--------+---------+----------+

   Usually this is due to dask's dtype inference failing, and
   *may* be fixed by specifying dtypes manually by adding:

   dtype={'641860': 'float64'}

   to the call to `read_csv`/`read_table`.

   Alternatively, provide `assume_missing=True` to interpret
   all unspecified integer columns as floats.
```

1. I dont have a column name called 641860 in df ( it did not have an header at first and picked the first line, but i added the header row to this with : df.rename cols.... and verified it has header. Why is it showing old name
2. How to merge the dask dataframes without getting the error above??
   I tried to change the col dtype to int64 and verified and it shows int64 when i do df.head

   ```
   <bound method _Frame.head of Dask DataFrame Structure:
             uuid county_geoid cbsa_geoid state_geoid   rent
     npartitions=765                                                  
                  int64        int64      int64       int64  int64
   ```

Comment: df.rename did you set inplace=True?

Comment: no i cant use inplace=true in dask dataframe.

Comment: Could it be, that this problem is caused by the left join logic? Is the column, it complains about in the "right" dataframe? does the problem also occur if you use "inner"? and one more thing, does it also occur, if you convert the column to float64 manually before you do the merge (in case assume_missing=True doesn't work)? The point is probably only that your merge can't fill the column for all records and for int datatypes that is a problem, because they can't represent missing values (floats can) and so this kind of implicit conversion usually happens in such cases.

Comment: Maybe you already thought about it but have you tried to convert `UUID` to `int`? Is it possible that in one dataframe this is null or that one of the partitions doesn't have headers?

Comment: Yeah tried those already, no headway into this issue @rpanai

Comment: @jottbe no i want to use it as left. the problem that it displays as error is in the left dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is happening in the `read_csv` call, well before any other operations that you ran, like rename or astype could be called.  To resolve the error, I recommend including the code that the error message suggests into your `read_csv` call.